# Where can I find H.264 standard?

Tags: standards, h.264, fuzzing

I would like to write a little fuzzer for H.264 but I am not aware about the file format.
Could you give me the standard please, in order to forge correct (and therefore incorrect) h.264 files.

Thanks
Mathias

Answer (score 19):

You can download a copy of it here:

http://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.264-200305-S!!PDF-E&type=items

Comment: Here is a more recent version https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.264-201610-I!!PDF-E&type=items

Comment: Here is a working link for the 2016 version: https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=f&id=T-REC-H.264-201610-S!!PDF-E&type=items

Answer (score 1):

H264 is not a file format, it is a video compression standard. It is usually contained in some other file format. The standard is for it ISO-14496 part 10 or ITU-T H.264 (also known as MPEG4 AVC) which are not freely available, you have to buy a copy from ISO.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC for more details.

Comment: Ok thanks ! Other question : what is the size of MPEG4 AVC header ? Because it is useless to fuzz the stream... Fuzzing the header is more interesting.

Comment: H.264 is a stream format, it does not have a "header" as such, so asking "how big is the header" is kind of a meaningless question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy the standard from the International Standards Organisation (ISO).

Comment: You can get it free from ITU, if you get it from ISO you have to pay... just differing pricing policies.